# Windows 10 Upgrade Installation Corrupt

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just upgraded my computer to Windows 10 from Windows 7 using the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

However, after the upgrade, my settings doesn't start. It just blinks then exits.

I did an "sfc /scannow" scan and it cannot repair the damage.

Here is the repair attempt log:

```
2015-07-30 04:14:39, Info                  CSI    00001391 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"Application.manifest" of microsoft-windows-immersivecontrolpanel.appxmain, Version = 10.0.10240.16384, pA = amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2015-07-30 04:14:41, Info                  CSI    000013cd [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"Application.manifest" of microsoft-windows-immersivecontrolpanel.appxmain, Version = 10.0.10240.16384, pA = amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2015-07-30 04:14:41, Info                  CSI    000013ce [SR] This component was referenced by [l:338{169}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-shell~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-shell-Deployment"
2015-07-30 04:14:41, Info                  CSI    000013d1 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:74{37},l:72{36}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\ImmersiveControlPanel"\[l:40{20}]"Application.manifest"; source file in store is also corrupted
2015-07-30 04:26:47, Info                  CSI    00005065 [SR] Repairing 1 components
2015-07-30 04:26:47, Info                  CSI    00005068 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"Application.manifest" of microsoft-windows-immersivecontrolpanel.appxmain, Version = 10.0.10240.16384, pA = amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2015-07-30 04:26:47, Info                  CSI    0000506b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"Application.manifest" of microsoft-windows-immersivecontrolpanel.appxmain, Version = 10.0.10240.16384, pA = amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2015-07-30 04:26:47, Info                  CSI    0000506c [SR] This component was referenced by [l:338{169}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-shell~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-shell-Deployment"
2015-07-30 04:26:47, Info                  CSI    0000506f [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:74{37},l:72{36}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\ImmersiveControlPanel"\[l:40{20}]"Application.manifest"; source file in store is also corrupted
2015-07-30 04:26:47, Info                  CSI    00005076 [SR] Repair complete
2015-07-30 04:26:47, Info                  CSI    00005077 [SR] Committing transaction
```

I created a USB recovery disk and tried to recover using DISM but it says the following error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:F:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess

Deployment Image Servicing and Management Tool
Version: 10.0.10240.16384

Image Version: 10.0.10240.16384

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. 
For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

It says the image cannot be found, but it actually IS there.

Any ideas?